# Xerox Phaser 8560 Error 7,010.43 10454 - help

Tags: printer

Hoping someone has a suggestion on resolving an error 7,010.43 10454 on a Xerox Phaser 8560.

I tried several power down / power up cycles.   I went in to service mode and ran various 'exercises' and everything seemed ok.  I also tried a reset ISC.

The maintenance kit was just changed and it looks ok.    I do not see any obvious issues looking in to the holes/doors.

I read that possibly the print head could be stuck or caught on the wiper, but pulling the top off I could not quickly identify what I am looking for - possibly a service manual would help.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So luckily the printer was under warranty and Xerox came.   It ended up being a couple serious issues internally according to the tech.  I believe one had to do with a bad board.